# smooth transition between hovered and normal state (using css3 animations)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

every time I use keyframes for on-hover animations, the animations stops on mouse leaves and roughly goes back to original state. Is there any chance to make the movement smoother? I tried using transitions, but they seem not to work with keyframes.

The example can be found below (at the moment I'm adding hovered class with jQuery, but the :hover doesn't work as well):
http://jsfiddle.net/42ZHq/

HTML

```
<div class="sign-container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.sign-container {
background:red;
width: 250px;
height: 238px;
margin:30px auto;
-webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 22% 0;
}


.sign-container.hovered {
animation: wiggle 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal;
-webkit-animation: wiggle 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal;
-moz-animation: wiggle 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal;
-ms-animation: wiggle 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal;
-o-animation: wiggle 2s ease-in-out 0s 1css n ormal;
-webkit-transform-origin:22% 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
25%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
75%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
25%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
75%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
}

@keyframes wiggle {
0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
25%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
50%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
75%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); }
}
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.sign-container', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).on('mouseleave', '.sign-container', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Thanks,
S.

PS. Don't hate for lack of proper prefixes please, was testing in Chrome...

Comment: the problem is that the animation is set only for the class `.hovered` when this class is remove on mouseleave (or mouseout) the element does not have an animation to do and that's why it does not do a trasition

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is quite the answer you are looking for, but here is a workaround that I came up with.

Your problem existed because you removed that class when the mouse left the div.  In reality, you don't want the class to be removed when the mouse leaves, **you want it to be removed when the animation is finished**.  So you can set a timer event to remove the class after ~2 seconds, and then you can re-play the animation over and over again.

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.sign-container', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('hovered')) {
        return false;   
    }
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function (event) {
        that.removeClass('hovered');
    }, 2000);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/42ZHq/3/

Comment: I found this solution in another topic on SO. This will do the trick for now (thank you very much :) ), but I'll wait with accepting the answer as the final one. I guess that to make it work with transitions, I'd have to replace keyframes with bare transforms... But it just won't work like this.

Comment: What kind of use-case are you looking for that would require a css solution over this one?  Perhaps I can help.

Comment: Well, clearly the suggested solution is not going to cover situations in which you can't specify the amount of cycles (i was trying to implement this one with infinity loop originally, just gave up, cause I couldn't find a way to do that for now).